# mapping state to props is returning undefined and does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am mapping my store state to my pagination component but it's returning undefined and only running one time when it's value is undefined not when it has value and i'm setting it to state and it's not updating the state too so i had to use store.subscribe method but this is not very good and how can i set the value to slicedPage outside the for loop so it won't run as many time as total_pages if i set outside the for loop it's empty and hope i explained it well

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../store";
import { all_Movies } from "../../actions";
```

My Pagination Class

```
export class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      one: 0,
      last: 10,
      total_pages: this.props.pages,
      pageNumber: [],
      slicedPage: []
    };
    store.subscribe(() => {
      if (store.getState().all_Movies.total_pages) {
        console.log(store.getState().all_Movies.total_pages);
        this.setState(
          { total_pages: store.getState().all_Movies.total_pages },
          () => {
            for (let i = 1; i < this.state.total_pages; i++) {
              this.setState(
                prevState => ({ pageNumber: [...prevState.pageNumber, i] }),
                () => {
                  // page.push(this.state.pageNumber[i])
                  // console.log(page);

                  this.setState({
                    one:
                      this.state.pageNumber.slice(
                        this.state.one,
                        this.state.last
                      ).length -
                      this.state.pageNumber.slice(
                        this.state.one,
                        this.state.last
                      ).length
                  });
                  this.setState({
                    last: this.state.pageNumber.slice(
                      this.state.one,
                      this.state.last
                    ).length
                  });
```

I want to set this outside the for Loop

```
                  this.setState({
                    slicedPage: this.state.pageNumber.slice(
                      this.state.one,
                      this.state.last
                    )
                  });
```

----------^^^^^^

```
                 console.log(this.state.one, this.state.last);
                }
              );
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pagination">
        <ul className="pagination_wrapper">
          {this.state.slicedPage.map(number => (
            <li key={number} className="pagination_link">
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.loadPage(number);
                }}
              >
                {number}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Mapping state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pages: state.all_Movies.total_pages,
  type: state.all_Movies.type
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { all_Movies }
)(Pagination);
```

Comment: Since you are using `connect` your Component gets updated every time there's a state change, no need to subscribe on your `store`. Also you may want your setup to be moved to `componentDidMount` method and have it set over there. You can get rid of all the `store.subscribe` callback rather just trust your prop to be updated. Also if you are getting a specific `prop`, no need to set it in your local `state` rather just rely on the `prop` direct.

Comment: it should get updated but it's not getting updated

Comment: i solved it thanks for help